# XeLaTeX pdfpages file size

Tags: xetex, pdf, size

I am using XeLaTeX to write my application. Everything was fine so far, but no I am adding pdf files with my certificates and the files size XeLatex is generating is about 36MB. Whereas the files I am ading alone maximum 7MB... I tried to reduce with ghostscript, but then I am loosing transparency information of my signature picture...

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r150 -sOutputFile=output.pdf file.pdf
```

Any ideas, why this is happening? Why is my pdf so big? I certainly can not send this as a job application. I was using latex to generate a nice looking application, in the end I will have one looking like MS Word 2.x

Comment: LaTeX does not change the size of included pdf files or image files. If you want to have a smaller resulting pdf reduce the size of included certificates.  How to do that depends on the images ... Reduce the dpi size to that size you use for your latex pdf file.

Comment: "Threatening" with the use of MS Word will not get you any better answers here.